# How to clone the object in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

```
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment attachments=null;

List<Attachment> clone = new ArrayList<Attachment>(attachments.size());
for(Object item: attachments) 
clone.add((Attachment)item.clone());//The method clone() from the type Object is not visible
```

I want to clone the `List<Attachment> clone` object but it saying The method clone() from the type Object is not visible

Comment: Does `Attachment` implement `Cloneable` or is it just an interface, i.e. does the implementation of `Attachment` implement `Cloneable`?

Comment: I think no, i can't see that its 3 party jar

Comment: Yes, looking at the online JavaDocs it doesn't seem so. In that case you can't call `clone` on `Attachment`. Maybe theres another way to clone them or maybe there's an entirely different way to achieve what you want. Btw, what is your ultimate goal with this?

Comment: I am reading List<Attachment> object twice but second time im not getting the Attachment content

Comment: Maybe you want to ask a question about that then. What I don't get: don't you get the attachments the second time you read them or are the attachment objects empty?

Comment: ya in second time attachment object is empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use Java standard `clone` method from `Object`. At least not before you read what Josh Bloch says about cloning in his book [Effective Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=effective%2Bjava%2Bclone&source=bl&ots=yXGhLnv4O4&sig=zvEip5tp5KGgwqO1sCWgtGyJ1Ns&hl=en&ei=CYANSqygK8jktgfM-JGcCA&sa=X&oi=book%5Fresult&ct=result&resnum=3#PPA54,M1).

You need to do a **deep copy** in this case i.e create an empty `ArrayList` of `Attachment` objects (which you did) and copy the **values** of all the fields of every `Attachment` object.

Answer (score 0):

A deep clone sample

```
 public static Object deepClone(Object model) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(model);

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        return ois.readObject();
    } 
    catch (IOException e)               { .. } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)    { .. }
    finally { /*close stream*/ }
}
```

Comment: This code expects that the `model` implements `java.io.Serializable`, which does not appear to be the case for `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment`.

Answer (score 0):

```
clone.add((Attachment)item.clone());//The method clone() from the type Object is not visible
```

The *actual* problem with this code is an operator precedence issue. Assuming the actual object is cloneable, and ignoring for the moment the issue of whether you should be cloning it at all, it should be written:

```
clone.add((Attachment)((Attachment)item).clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last line as:

```
clone.add(((Attachment)item).clone());
```

Make sure the `Attachment` implements the interface `Cloneable`